# Paper work before I do make my own Line follower Robot

Tags: mobile-robot

I am a graduate student trying to make my own Line follower Robot for my minor assessment, I've all **hardware** parts and all **data-sheets** with me, I've attended a workshops of Robotics and studied a lot on **Line follower robot**. I have a good knowledge of C Programming and Embedded systems, but the problem is I've a very **limited amount** of time(2 days).

Please help me to suggest a good paper work about my Project - Line follower robot, where should I start from ? I am getting myself confused should I start from **Programming** or should I first do circuit **simulations** as I know It is not a better approach to use directly hardware.

Please suggest me a fine **Paper work** or some links/videos so that I can make my Robotics projects fast. Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: As is, this question is not very answerable because there are *many* ways to solve this problem in hardware and software (and various combinations of the two).  What hardware have you purchased already?  What is your design so far?  What practical problem have you run into at this stage?

Comment: I've bought diodes, LED s, battery etc. I've completed my Designing and now I just have to burn my program. It is going to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two days?  Eeek!

I wouldn't try to simulate the thing at a circuit level.  If you're an EE and you're familiar with circuit simulation packages then using SPICE (or whatever) to simulate the *system* may let you slide by with an acceptable performance.

Personally, if I were designing one of these for money, I'd probably simulate it in Scilab, possibly using Xcos -- but that's because I'm familiar with that tool.

Given your limited time I wouldn't try to do more than make something that follows straight lines and gentle curves at some fixed speed.

Comment: I've programmed its .hex file and everything seems fine now, but simulation is not going to be easy, I am using ISIS professional , Do you think it is a good software for circuit simulation ?